# Stuck on loop to find the sum and average

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

This is my second time using stack overflow and I am just starting to code.

Write a class named Assignment4a that prompts the user to enter the number of students and then asks them to enter the exam grades for those students.  Your program will then calculate and print the sum and  average exam grade for the class.

```
import java.util.Scanner; 

public class Homework5A { 
   public static void main (String[]args) {
      Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

      String student;
      int grades = 0;
      double sum = 0;
      double avg = 0;

      for(int i=1; i<=grades; i++) {
         System.out.println("How many students?" );
         student= kbd.nextLine();
         System.out.println("Enter " + student + " grades: ");
         grades= kbd.nextInt();
         System.out.print("Sum: " + sum);
         sum = sum + grades; 
         }

      System.out.println("Average " + sum/students);



   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 for(int i=1; i<=grades; i++) {}
```

You can not initialize your for-loop statement which is start from 1 and finish at 0 (because current grades = 0).

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 import java.util.Scanner;

  import java.util.Scanner; 
   public class Test {

   public static void main (String[]args) {
      Scanner kbd = new Scanner(System.in);

      int student;
      int grades = 0;
      double sum = 0;
      double avg = 0;

      System.out.println("How many students?" );
         student= kbd.nextInt();
         System.out.println("Enter " + student + " grades: ");
      for(int i=0; i<student; i++) {
         grades= kbd.nextInt();
         sum = sum + grades; 
         System.out.println("Sum: " + sum);
         }

      System.out.println("Average " + sum/student);



   }
}
```

`

Comment: It's displaying this: 
How do you only display the whole Sum and Average instead of each one?

Enter 3 grades: 
100 95 90
Sum: 100.0
Average 33.333333333333336
Sum: 195.0
Average 65.0
Sum: 285.0
Average 95.0